# function (F1) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to enter any word and then press the button to get the result.

The result is **"hello"**.

Can anyone help me to figure out why the result doesn't appear when I render it?

```
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <script>
          function start() { 
              var button = document.getElementById("add" );
              button.addEventListener( "click", t, false );
          }

          function t() {  
             r.innerHTML = "Hello";
             window.addEventListener( "load", start, false );
          }         
      </script>     
   </head>
```

Please help if you know what is wrong in my code.

Comment: This is not written in standard JavaScript.

Comment: ... or standard HTML, for that matter ;-)

Comment: This looks like reasonably normal HTML and JavaScript to me... Not sure what you two are on about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is that your entire code? I don't see a call to start()

Your current call embedded in `F1` needs to be moved out of the function into the main code so that it runs when the page is loaded:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", start, false );

function start()
...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uU2K7/

Comment: The real problem is that there is a call to `start` embedded in `F1` (`window.addEventListener( "load", start, false );`) which needs to be moved outside of the function call: http://jsfiddle.net/uU2K7/